# How to set Java/Scala tests' system properties through maven plugin?

Tags: java, scala, maven, unit-testing, properties

I would like to run my test with 2 different profiles, each set a Java property that results in my scala test code being executed differently.

I tried configuring both maven-surefire and maven-scalatest plugins:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <systemProperties>
                    <spark.master>local</spark.master>
                </systemProperties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <spark.master>local</spark.master>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

but seems like non of them works, when executing System.getProperty("spark.master") the result is still null. What should I do to enable this setting?

//-----------------------------------------------

Response to the first answer:

I've changed my surefire config into the following:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <spark.master>${spark.master}</spark.master>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <forkCount>1</forkCount>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

but apparently the  is in the wrong place. Maven gave me this error:

```
[ERROR]     Malformed POM /home/peng/git/datapassport/pom.xml: Unrecognised tag: 'systemPropertyVariables' (position: START_TAG seen ...</goals>\n                        <systemPropertyVariables>... @170:50)  @ /home/peng/git/datapassport/pom.xml, line 170, column 50 -> [Help 2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) if you use JUnit - upgrade its version to 4.7 or higher and specify explicit provider:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.1</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

(b) in surefire plugin configuration specify

```
<forkCount>1</forkCount>
```

(c) use plugun's executions maven mechanism to run two different profiles

```
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>tests-1</id>
        <goals><goal>test</goal></goals>
        <configuration>
            <systemProperyVariables ... />
        </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
        <id>tests-2</id>
        <goals><goal>test</goal></goals>
        <configuration>
            <systemProperyVariables ... />
        </configuration>
    </execution>
```

Comment: Are you sure this is where systemProperyVariables should be? The schema definition indicates that it doesn't belong to <execution>. Plz see my detailed response above

Comment: In the meantime, I'm wondering if this solution works in IDE-generated test as well? the goals in execution seems to indicates that it only works in mvn test

Comment: @tribbloid I've added lost <configuration> tag into answer. If you run maven target from IDE - solution will work. If you run a single test in IDE - you should provide -Dspark.master=<some value> into run configuration JVM options.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I guess its a IDE lacking of feature. This works as proven by my test